# On average, how often do people thru hiking the Pacific Crest Trail resupply?

Tags: backpacking, thru-hike, pacific-crest-trail

I have been wondering how often the thru-hikers on the [Pacific Crest Trail](http://www.pcta.org/discover-the-trail/) resupply. I would assume that it depends on the part of the trail and the hiker, but is there an average distance or length of time between resupplies?

Comment: I don't know about people on PCT, but I find that going more than 5-7 days on one supply of food gets heavy and takes a lot of room in your bag (and it gets boring too, as the type of food gets constrained to really energy- and volume-efficient. Basically just peanut butter at some point)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the [2016 Halfway Anywhere Survey](http://www.halfwayanywhere.com/trails/pacific-crest-trail/pacific-crest-trail-thru-hiker-survey-2016/) of PCT hikers:

- The average days on trail was 145 and the length is 2,650 miles (4265 km).
- The average number of resupply stops was 26
- If you subtract the average of 17 zero days (days without mileage) and 13 near-zeros, we have 115 days of actual walking, meaning the average hiker was carrying 4-5 days of supplies per leg and averaged 23 miles (37 km) per active day.